# Basic NGINX proxy_pass example is serving 404's

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have an very basic out-of-the-box NGINX server running on a Windows machine at `http://10.0.15.19:80`. I'm attempting to use it as a proxy to get around a CORS restriction. I have the following `nginx.conf`, which from every example I've seen sounds like it should redirect any traffic from `http://10.0.15.19` to `http://10.0.1.2:3000`.

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  10.0.15.19;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://10.0.1.2:3000/;
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of serving the content from `http://10.0.1.2:3000` I get the default index.html page inside the included html folder. Similarly, if I were to go to http://10.0.15.19/any/path I get a 404 even though http://10.0.1.2:3000/any/path works correctly.

[image: gif of requests to 10.0.1.2:3000 and 10.0.15.19]

EDIT: I've noticed that even after commenting out the entire `server` block of my configuration, it's still serving content from the included html folder. This makes me think there is another server configuration running that I'm not aware of, but I'm not sure where. I downloaded NGINX from [here](http://nginx.org/en/download.html), and I assume all configuration files exist within this folder.

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash in proxy_pass; -> `proxy_pass http://10.0.1.2:3000;`

Comment: Have you reloaded/restarted nginx after modifying the config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was because simply closing the window that pops up when you open nginx.exe doesn't actually kill the process. And in Windows you can apparently have multiple services bound to the same port, so I had many servers serving on port 80. Killing all of these processes and relaunching with the originally posted config fixed my problem.

[image: task manager showing lots of nginx.exe processes]